# SiteRules in SEO URLs

Tags: outsystems

have created a Site Rule in SEO URL for example icommute.abc.org and it is using the espace iCommute.
I want to access the application using the SEO URL. When I try https://icommute.abc.org/ it doesnot open my application I even tried https://icommute.abc.org/iCommute or https://icommute.abc.org/iCommute/Login.aspx.

I tried www.icommute.abc.org and www.icommute.abc.org/iCommute.  But nothing seems to be working.

Let me what is the mistake i am doing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site rules allow you to place a selected application at the root of an OutSystems server.

You specify the hostname that should be matched in every URL and (whenever you reach the server via

> < someprotocol >://< host >/< MyPage.aspx >

the MyPage page of the selected application should be available there.

If that isn't working it could be due to many things:

1. You typed in a protocol together with the host in the rule (i.e. use **icommute.abc.org** not *https://icommute.abc.org/*;
2. You are using https://icommute.abc.org/ (no page) but iCommute doesn't have a default entry point;
3. The SEO filter is not installed in the server in the first place;

Let us know.